# Populating DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I tried to search for an answer for my qestion, but I didn't find any suitable solution.

Here's the deal:

I have a CSV file with unknown amount of columns and I have to show it in datagrid or listview. In addition, every row must have an additional checkbox column to specify if user wants to do sth with this row or not. I think I can use DataTemplate in xaml to create this extra column, but I don't actually know how to fill control with data so it can display it properly.

In Windows Forms it was simple - create DataTable and inject it to datagridview. As I am new to WPF, I don't know where to go.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, populating controls with data is usually performed with [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx) in the XAML.

Try reading that article, and doing some research into WPF data binding and data/item templates.

Comment: Thanks, I will read it. I have performed some data binding before, but it was simple - with custom objects with defined properties to display.